# Does OpenEBS support ReadOnlyMany option for Jiva Volumes?

Tags: kubernetes, storage, openebs

Regarding OpenEBS iscsi provisioner: How to use `ReadOnlyMany` with iscsi?

When I apply it on kubernetes pod it gives the following error:

> (x12 over )  openebs.io/provisioner-iscsi
>   openebs-provisioner-5569654c96-4rlsn
>   760ae66d-9ebc-11e8-97d4-823996605407  Failed to provision volume with
>   StorageClass "openebs-standard": Invalid Access Modes: [ReadOnlyMany],
>   Supported Access Modes: [ReadWriteOnce]

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer no. Most volume types in Kubernetes are supported as `ReadWriteOnce`.

Use cases for `ReadOnlyMany` are limited. If you are trying to share things among pods you can take a look at [ConfigMaps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) or [Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/)